# Canon R5C Photo review play button showing wrong image

Tags: canon, mirrorless

I recently switched from the Canon R5 to the Canon R5C. Typically, when I take a photo on my Canon R5 and press the play button, it immediately shows me the photo I just took. This is how all digital cameras should behave, and it's very straightforward. Click the photo, press the play button, and you'll see the preview.

However, with my new Canon R5C (with firmware 1.0.2.1, the latest as of March 2023), things are different. The camera takes a few seconds to load the photo, and instead of showing a 'busy, please wait' message, it shows a photo that was previously taken. It only displays the 'please wait' message if the memory card is empty because there are no other photos to show.

This can be very frustrating when I'm shooting events because I take a photo, and when I review it, I find a problem. I correct the problem in my next shot, but when I press the play button, the camera shows me the previous photo again. This is confusing and makes me think I made the mistake again.

Can anyone explain is this a bug? .Anyone else experiencing this issue?, And can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find a solution to the issue I was facing. It turned out to be a bug specific to the Canon Eos R5C, and it's uncertain whether the same bug is present in other models. The problem stemmed from a combination of certain image settings, which caused the camera to take longer than usual to process images. If there were no images saved on the memory card, the camera would display a "busy, please wait" message. However, if there was a previous image on the camera, it would display the latest one in the list, causing confusion and frustration. If the camera settings were normal, the image would write to the memory card quickly,No problems.

Ideally, if the camera was taking time to save an image to the memory card, it should display the "busy, please wait" message, regardless of whether the memory card was empty or not. I was able to fix this problem by resetting the camera settings, but if I want to use the previous settings, I will have to deal with this bug again.

Comment: Great finding and thanks for sharing the solution.